$\int^0_{-\log(2)}|f(e^x)\cdot\frac{1-x}{e^x}|dx$ Where $f$ is given
$$\int^0_{-\log(2)}|f(e^x)\cdot\frac{1-x}{e^x}|dx$$
Where $f(x)=\frac{\log(x)+x}{x}$
Firstly we find the roots of this function , $f(e^x)=0  $ or $x=1\notin(-\log(2),0) \iff e^x=x_0\iff x=\log(x_0)$. where $x_0$ is the only root of $f$ .
Let $g(x)=f(e^x)\cdot\frac{1-x}{e^x}$
So $$I=\int^{\log(x_0)}_{-\log(2)}|g(x)|dx+\int_{\log(x_0)}^0|g(x)|dx=I_1+I_2$$
For every $-\log(2)\leq x \leq\log(x_0)\iff e^{-\log(2)}\leq e^x \leq e^{\log(x_0)}\iff \frac{1}{2}\leq x\leq x_0$ And since $f$ is increasing on that interval $f(\frac{1}{2})\leq f(e^x)\leq f(x_0)\iff f(e^x)\leq0$
Therefore, $g(x)=f(e^x)\frac{1-x}{e^x}\leq0$
So $$I_1=-\int^{\log(x_0)}_{-\log(2)}g(x)dx=-\int^{\log(x_0)}_{-\log(2)}f(e^x)\frac{1-x}{e^x}dx$$
Let $u=e^x$
$$I_1=-\int^{x_0}_{1/2}f(u)\frac{1-\log(u)}{u^2}du=-\int^{x_0}_{1/2}f(u)f'(u)du=-\frac{1}{2}\left[f^2(u)\right]_{1/2}^{x_0}=\frac{1}{2}f^2(\frac{1}{2})$$
Similarly, for every $\log(x_0)\leq x\leq 0 \iff 0\leq f(e^x)$
$$I_2=\int^1_{x_0}f(u)f'(u)du=\frac{1}{2}f^2(1)$$
Therefore
$$I=I_1+I_2= 1-2\log(2)+2\log^2(2)$$
Q: Is there any quicker/ simpler way to solve this ?

Let $W(1) \equiv W$ the root of $e^x + x = 0$ (named as ProductLog). Then, the integral can be splited in
$$I =\int_{-\log(2)}^0 \left|\frac{(x+e^x)(1-x)}{e^{2x}}\right|\text{d}x = \int_{-\log(2)}^{-W} \frac{(x+e^x)(x-1)}{e^{2x}}\text{d}x + \int_{-W}^0 \frac{(x+e^x)(1-x)}{e^{2x}}\text{d}x = I_1+ I_2$$
For the first integral:
$$I_1 = \int_{-\log(2)}^{-W} \frac{(x+e^x)(x-1)}{e^{2x}}\text{d}x = \frac{1}{2}e^{2W}W(2e^{-W} - W) - \frac{4}{2}\log(2)[1-\log(2)].$$
Observe that $(2e^{-W} - W) = e^{-W}$ and $We^W = 1$ by the definition of $W$, so the integral reduces to
$$I_1 = \frac{1}{2} - 2\log(2)[1-\log(2)] = \frac{1}{2}[\log(4)-1]^2.$$
Analogously, you can check that
$$I_2 = \int_{-W}^0 \frac{(x+e^x)(1-x)}{e^{2x}}\text{d}x = \frac{1}{2}.$$
Then, you get
$$I = I_1 + I_2 = \frac{1}{2}[1 + \log^2(4) -2\log(4)].$$
